# Use key as byte array for DES3 in python

Tags: python, pycryptodome

I have a key and IV for DES3 as byte array (generated by C#):

```
var _algo = TripleDES.Create();
_algo.GenerateIV();
_algo.GenerateKey();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", _algo.IV));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", _algo.Key));
```

I get these values for example:

```
[220, 138, 91, 56, 76, 81, 217, 70]
[88, 221, 70, 78, 149, 105, 62, 50, 93, 32, 72, 240, 54, 53, 153, 41, 39, 135, 78, 19, 216, 208, 180, 50]
```

How do I properly use the key to decode the message in Python? I'm trying:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

codedText = "hvAjofLh4mc="

iv = [220, 138, 91, 56, 76, 81, 217, 70]
key = [88, 221, 70, 78, 149, 105, 62, 50, 93, 32, 72, 240, 54, 53, 153, 41, 39, 135, 78, 19, 216, 208, 180, 50]
cipher_encrypt = DES3.new(bytearray(key), DES3.MODE_CBC, bytearray(iv))
v = cipher_encrypt.decrypt(codedText)
```

This gives me

```
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

But I think I am doing something wrong with the keys.

The code I used to generate the keys/message in C#:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/PXcNhl

Comment: In this scenario I would first try, to give the codedText as bytestring `b"hvAj..."`. This should fix the reported error.

Comment: @guidot yes, but in my mind this is what `bytearray(key)` is doing. I need to start from the array as it is written - as this is what I get from C# code

Comment: Which line the message refers to? You don't seem to apply bytearray to codedText, so this needs to be fixed anyway. (Assuming Python3)

Comment: @guidot The error is reported on `.decrypt` call. I didn't apply it to `codedText` because I saw examples that has normal strings there. I'll try, maybe this is the problem

Comment: @guidot using `.encode('utf-8')` removes the error but still does not decode the message. I get "Data must be padded to 8 byte boundary in CBC mode' error in the example above (should decode to "Test") and gibberish with my real data

Comment: @guidot I have added a link to C# code I used to generate the keys/codedText

Comment: a) `.encode('utf-8')` creates the correct data type, but is a pretty meaningless operation for a cryptogram.  b) You can't decrypt an arbitrary length byte string when using a block cipher, the cryptogram has to be a multiple of the block size (i. e. 8 bytes).

Comment: @guidot Yes, I think I have a misalignment between C# and Python. I just realized C# produces b64 string so I might try to decode that

Comment: @guidot Thanks for the guidance. Yes, converting from b64 to bytearray helped, I receive a proper message now (for some reason with `\x02\x02` in the end, but that are details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize some findings from the comments:

- For crypto libraries under Python 3 the input and output need to be byte strings or byte literals (`b"something"`).
- While for plaintext `.encode('utf-8')` results in the corect data type, it is unnecessary for Python 3 (where strings are always unicode) and a meaningless operation for ciphertext.
- If a given ciphertext has not a size, which is an exact multiple of the block size of the (symmetric) algorithm, it may be given in a special encoding (like base64) to avoid binary 0 characters or other stuff, which may be difficult to represent.